# Yii: Fixer - how can I create relations between fixtures?

Tags: php, testing, yii, yii2

I have two question about Yii2 Fixtures. Does somebody knows how can I create relations between fixtures?

1. How can I create a **parent-child** fixture relation?
   The models have `parent_id`, but I do not know how I can attach the fixture.
2. How can I create **belongs-to** fixture relation?
   Like between the category and product models?

I have read the guide but I did not recognize how I can do this. Or does somebody has any good example about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:
You have **User**, **Post** tables. Relation by "user_id" field in **Post** table.

You create fixture **UserFixture**, with data:

```
return [
 'user1' => [
    'id'=>1
    'username' => 'lmayert',
    'email' => 'strosin.vernice@jerde.com',
    'auth_key' => 'K3nF70it7tzNsHddEiq0BZ0i-OU8S3xV',
    'password' => '$2y$13$WSyE5hHsG1rWN2jV8LRHzubilrCLI5Ev/iK0r3jRuwQEs2ldRu.a2',
 ]
];
```

After that fixture **Post** with data:

```
return [
  ['post1' => ['id'=>1,'user_id'=>1,'title'=>'example']
];
```

And if you want you can create dependency in Post:

```
namespace app\tests\fixtures;

use yii\test\ActiveFixture;

class PostFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Post';
    public $depends = ['app\tests\fixtures\UserFixture'];
}
```